# Create a new primary partition in Ubuntu for new OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I want to create a new primary partition on my Ubuntu server to install CentOS and use a boot manager to switch between Ubuntu and Cent OS. I have the following questions:

1. How do I create a new primary partition for installing CentOS? I had tried fdisk /dev/sda and the respective commands to create a primary partition but it doesn't appear when I view my partitions.
2. Once I have installed CentOS on my new primary partition how do I switch between Ubuntu and CentOS? I have come across GRUB and other boot managers like zBootManager,Boot-US but would appreciate if someone could provide suggestions on which one is better.

Comment: Please remember the forum rule: ONE question per topic.

Comment: Have you used all 4 primary partitions. Or is system gpt partitioned with no primary partitions? Post this: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can simply shrink your ubuntu partition, and the installer for CentOS should let you use that space. I don't know the CentOS installer well, so in reality the answer is that you should shrink your Ubuntu partition using GParted or similar, then follow the installation instructions for CentOS to install it onto the free space you've created. If you need assistance with CentOS, you should use their forums.
2. GRUB is probably the most suited boot manager, this question seems to be more opinionated though (going against the regulations of this site). With regards to selecting which OS on boot, you will be prompted with a command line UI and asked to select an OS. If you don't select one within 10 seconds or so, it will automatically select your "primary" OS, which in my experience is the last one you installed, but you can change this within Ubuntu or CentOS.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and for this concept of Gparted!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `fdisk` if you are not sure what you are going to do. Use Gparted instead. You can not edit the partition with your current OS, too. So boot your PC from Ubuntu USB stick or any other LiveCD that contains Gparted, and use it to resize and create partitions. Backup important data before that!

Answer (score 0):

1. Why struggle with fdisk? Just install GParted and use it graphically. Or use it directly from an Ubuntu LiveDVD/LiveUSB. GParted sees any and all partitions. Guaranteed.
2. GRUB will install automatically with Ubuntu and CentOS. You should be fine with it. The ultimate boot manager i believe is rEFInd, but i wouldn't rush into it unless i know very well what i'm doing.